# ubuntu data recovery help

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, data-recovery

recently I have install  Ubuntu 13.04 removing windows 7 . before installing Ubuntu in win 7 there are 5 partition storing my  important data but after installing  Ubuntu all partition merged into single one and delete my all earlier data but I want to get back my those all data please give me useful information to help

Comment: Check this answer:http://askubuntu.com/questions/286181/how-do-i-recover-my-accidentally-lost-windows-partitions-after-installing-ubuntu/286206#286206

Answer (score -1):

Well, there is hope, but it will be tricky.
First, power off the computer. Never switch it on again until data is recovered. Hopefully previous data is still there, until it is overwritten. Obviously, you'll need another computer into which you'll mount your damaged HD in read-only mode. Alternatively, you'll need a new hard drive in the same computer, that you'll set as the boot drive, still mounting the damaged HD as secondary, read-only. Yet another alternative would be to boot in a live USB-stick, itself partitioned to allow some persistent data.

Now for the hardest part : you absolutely need the previous partition map. Start sector, end sector and exact size of each partition. If you wrote this down somewhere, or have an exceptional memory, you can proceed. If no, skip to "forensics" below.

So say you know the previous partition map. Just partion (e.g. with gparted) anew as it was before, format the partitions as NTFS and you *may* find your data exactly as it was, with the exception of *some* files which were overwritten while installing and running Ubuntu. It happened to me once, it was quite mesmerizing. Now, I had it easier as I had only *one* partition, so the previous partition map was straightforward.

Absent previous partition map, skip into forensics mode. I did that when upgrade to 13.04 proved to be the upgrade from hell for some reasons. I dont remember what tool I used. The good news is that I recovered *some* files. Bad news number one was that I didn't recover them all. Bad news #2 was that none of them had a name any more. I was left with a bunch of direcories named like recov_dir.153 holding files like f1393216.jpg (or whatever extension) so thereafter lots of manual hard work to figure out what is what.

Summary : hope exists, brace for hard work, expect some loss.

Comment: Could you instead provide the steps, commands to do so? I know what are you talking about but anyone else could not. Please, describe the tools that would be useful in this case and how to use them.